# Changing Foundation's topbar breakpoint with custom CSS?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to move from Bootstrap to Foundation, but I'm having an issue in trying to identify how to exactly change the breakpoint for the topbar in Foundation. I'm using a a CDN version of the minified CSS for Foundation, so I do NOT have access to the settings SASS file to modify this. Is there a quick CSS override workaround? So far my searches on here, and Google, haven't turned up a working solution.

Comment: some pictures of the problem or erros from console can be useful

Comment: There aren't any errors or pictures to show, I just want to know what I need to override in CSS to change the breakpoint at which the top nav collapses to a mobile view.

Comment: something like this? http://www.codeply.com/go/GVsytKbMkV

Answer (score 0):

Import another CSS file below the minified Foundation CSS that will target the topbar

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="override.css">
```

So, for example, if `.topbar` has `margin: 1px;` override it on override.css by setting another `margin: 2px;` attribute there.

This post will help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31511646/6294600

Have you checked this one https://zurb.com/university/lessons/change-foundation-s-default-breakpoints

EDIT: a hint here...

look for the `.show-for-medium` class... I hope you know what to do after that... Don't give up...

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
  .hide-for-small-only {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 0em), screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .show-for-small-only {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .hide-for-medium {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
  .show-for-medium {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .hide-for-medium-only {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em), screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .show-for-medium-only {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .hide-for-large {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .show-for-large {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) and (max-width: 74.9375em) {
  .hide-for-large-only {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 63.9375em), screen and (min-width: 75em) {
  .show-for-large-only {
    display: none !important; } }
```

These parts can be found in
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.css

Change the values, I hope this answers the question. Happy Coding...

LAST BIT OF INFO:

change the min-width size

```
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .top-bar{
    display:none;
   }
 }
```

Comment: So I an including a custom CSS file for my overrides, but I need to specifically target the media query(ies) that are telling the top bar to collapse when it does. I need to be able to have the top bar collapse sooner than what it is using CSS overrides.Since I'm new to using Foundation, I'm not sure what those are, and the Foundation Docs aren't helping.

Comment: Get the non-minified version of Foundation, search for the media queries then, copy the whole block of that specific media query, place it in your overrides.css.

Comment: added a link that can help you in solving your problem

Comment: That's the problem, there don't appear to be any that are specific to ".top-bar", the element that is being hidden and displayed by the media queries.The link you provided only talks about changing the grid, which isn't something I want to do, just a specific media query on an element.

Comment: I've been saying all along that the media query for the top-bar needs to be overridden, this much I know. Looking at the unminified CSS file for Foundation, no such media query exists. My original question still hasn't been answered, WHAT needs to be overridden.

Comment: This still doesn't address navigation, these media queries are NOT fro that.

Comment: mate, what version of Foundation are you using? what is the class of your <nav> or your target element? Those are the media queries handling the breakpoint. If you still can't fix it by modifying the above queries in your override.css, then I'm afraid that I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: Read the final bit of Info i've made.

Comment: Foundation 6. The media queries you've include below are only targeting the ".show-for-SIZE-only", there isn't a single one that targets the nav. The default foundation class is ".top-bar".